# MS-Access LIKE another column

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col1 LIKE *a.col2*
```

where I'm looking for values in col1 that are a superset string of those in col2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the clause as a string:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col1 LIKE "*" & a.col2 & "*"
```